# How does it work? Delimiter and the Extended Addressing in my program

Tags: assembly, tasm

BOOK: IBM PC Assembly Language Programming: Fifth Edition by Peter Abel

p.143 Program: Accepting and Displaying Names

> The `movzx` sets `BX` with the number of characters that were typed. In the `mov,[bx]` acts as an index register to facilitate extended addressing. The `MOV` combines the length in `BX` with the address of `KBNAME` and moves the `07H` to the calculated address. for a lenth of 11, the instruction inserts `07H` at `KBNAME+11` (replacing the Enter character) following the name. The instruction in c10center
>
> ```
> mov kbname[bx+1],'$'
> ```
>
> inserts a `$` delimiter following the `07H` so that `int 21h` function `09H` can display the name and sound the speaker
>
> ```
> 1  c10center proc near
> 2  movzx bx,actulen
> 3  mov kbname[bx],07
> 4  mov kbname[bx+1],'$'
> 5  mov dl,actulen
> 6  shr dl,1
> 7  neg dl
> 8  add dl,40
> 9  mov dh,12
> 10 call q20cursor
> 11 ret
> 12 c10center endp
> ```

my question is what does the `,07` in line 3 do?

also i am confused how does line 4 works? delimiter?

Comment: If you're just trying to learn asm, learning DOS system calls at the same time makes it harder, IMO.  You can learn 32 or 64bit asm first, so you can write functions you can call from normal programs.  (See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), there are a couple tutorials and a couple links with suggestions about learning asm.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 3: it's putting the "bell" character (indeed, character 7; it's called bell because the computer beeps when printing it) in the position specified by `bx` of the buffer `kbname`. Notice that it had first to move (with zero-extension, so I suppose it's some kind of 8-bit value?) `actulen` in `bx`, because in 16 bit x86 it's one or the few registers that can be used in indexed addressing modes.

Line 4 does a similar thing, but with the `$` character at the next position in the string.

In C, these two lines would just be

```
kbname[actulen] = 7;
kbname[actulen+1] = '$';
```

The book talks about a "delimiter" because `int 21h/ah=09h` uses `$` as a marker that the string it has to display has ended. In this respect, in DOS assembly programming $-terminated ("ASCII$") strings are really similar to C's NUL-terminated ("ASCIIZ") strings (actually, the delimiter choice is way stupider, since $ is a character that does occur in "normal" strings you'd like to display).

Comment: sir i have a question in line 4,  `mov kbname[bx+1]` , why does bx have plus 1 what is the bearing of it on this function

Comment: Because it's accessing position bx+1, i.e. actulen+1. In position actulen he puts the bell character, in the following one the string terminator.